# Difference between (.+?) and (.*?) in regular expressions

Tags: regex

I would like to know what the difference is between `(.+?)` and `(.*?)`

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `.+?` form requires at least one character to match, while `.*?` can match none at all.  Both operations are non-greedy, so they will try to find the shortest possible matching string.

Comment: Thanks for the non-greedy headsup. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression "modern regular expression tools allow a quantifier to be specified as lazy (also known as non-greedy, reluctant, minimal, or ungreedy) by putting a question mark after the quantifier (e.g., <.*?>)"